# Scheduled alarm not working on boot

Tags: java, android

I used a receiver which would start a service on boot. In the services onCreate i put in a scheduled alarm. This is only executed once. Why? Here is the code for the service which is called by the receiver on boot

```
/**
 * Created by rishabh on 24/3/16.
*/
public class MyServiceOnBoot extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MyServiceOnBoot.this,MyABService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MyServiceOnBoot.this, 0, intent2, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm_manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, c.getTimeInMillis(), 1*1000,  pintent);
    stopSelf();
}
}
```

The MyABService class is only executed once. What could be the solution for it?
Here is the receiver class

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyServiceOnBoot.class);
    context.startService(startServiceIntent);
}
}
```

Here is the Manifest

```
  <service android:name=".MyABService"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.todaysfuture.dynpin.MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: did you add permission or not in mainfest file

Comment: i did. thats why its working. otherwise it wouldnt be working at all

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android

Comment: i used this. the issue is the alarm not the service

Comment: paste ur mainfest file please

Comment: done. its at the bottom

Comment: check ur name of the service i think ur class name and MainFest name is different

Comment: what happens if you set the alarm in `MyReceiver#onReceive()` , not in `MyServiceOnBoot`?

Comment: Hey its working now. I solved it. Thank you all

Comment: it will be good to post an answer for what you did, you know in case someone got this issue